# Applying a Django queryset filter using an attribute value AND exists()

Tags: python, django

I have two models, as follows:

```
class Link(models.Model):
    description = models.TextField(validators=[MaxLengthValidator(500)])
    submitter = models.ForeignKey(User)
    submitted_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Publicreply(models.Model):
    submitted_by = models.ForeignKey(User)
    answer_to = models.ForeignKey(Link)
    submitted_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    description = models.TextField(validators=[MaxLengthValidator(250)])
```

I need to retrieve all `Link` objects that were submitted by `user`, and that have **at least one** `Publicreply`. I'm trying to wrap my ahead around this, it's going to be something like `Link.objects.filter(submitter=user, Link.public_set.exists())`? Or what? Advise please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can get the result you want with this line:

```
Link.objects.filter(submitter=user, publicreply__isnull=False)
```

Comment: btw, I should be able to put that in a Q object and OR it with another statement too right? I.e. something like `Link.objects.filter(Q(submitter=user, publicreply__isnull=False)|Q(id__in=*some other criteria))`

Comment: I think you should, have you get some error while trying?